# Dynamic table in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in my application that allows users to add/remove records dynamically. Currently I am using a partial view and updating the table from the server for an add/delete request. What I would like is for this all to be handled on the client side, and I'm very close but I'm stuck on generating the correct indexes for my list items. The table is populated by a collection of a custom object property on my model.

**Example:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...

    IList<CustomObject> ThisCollectionPopulatesTheTable { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the idea from [this](http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/) fantastic tutorial on adding items dynamically to a table.

Here is the example from the tutorial that illustrates the adding of a row. This is more or less exactly what I'm doing, but a simpler example for the purpose of this question.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        var itemIndex = $("#container input.iHidden").length;
        e.preventDefault();
        var newItem = $("<tr><td><input id='Interests_" + itemIndex + "__Id' type='hidden' value='' class='iHidden'  name='Interests[" + itemIndex + "].Id' /><input type='text' id='Interests_" + itemIndex + "__InterestText' name='Interests[" + itemIndex + "].InterestText'/></td><td><input type='checkbox' value='true'  id='Interests_" + itemIndex + "__IsExperienced' name='Interests[" + itemIndex + "].IsExperienced' /></tr>");
        $("#container").append(newItem);
    });
});
```

The index is being generated based on the number of items, which is great when you only want to add items. The problem is that in my case, when the user can remove items as well, I end up with gaps. I thought about going through every item and doing some kind of replace to re-create all indexes each time an item is added but a) I haven't quite worked out the syntax and b) I'm not sure it's the best/most efficient solution.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can always have the correct indexes no matter what the user does as far as adding/removing items?

Comment: Are you removing whole  `<tr>`? If it is then there will be no issues for the gap!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Yeah i'm removing the whole row. The issue is if the user removes a row in the middle, the index for every row after is off. They can remove any row, it doesn't just remove the last entry. Sorry, I didn't make that clear!

Comment: @aw04 I suppose you need the index for the model binder right?

Comment: @Leron Exactly. It will not bind correctly if the index is wrong.

Comment: @aw04 Well, I can't provide you with a solution, but can share my experience with this problem. I personally was unable to find a satisfying solution so I solved it by leaving the back end to deal with this. However I think you have two choices - 1) use `Ajax.BeginForm()` and recreate the whole table; 2) Create another JS function to reindex every time a row is removed/added.

Comment: @Leron Thanks for the advice. You're probably right, I was hoping I'd missed something but it doesn't look like there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @aw04 In fact... the user can delete row from the middle but what are the rules for adding new row. Is it only as a last row or it may be everywhere?

Comment: I would suggest learning a client side framework such as Knockout. It can make your life a lot easier. (telling this by experience) and using knockout, you can do this dynamic behavior very easily. I'm sure everyone agrees.

Comment: @Leron When they add a new row it appends it to the end.

Comment: @Dirnthelord Thanks for the idea. I've thought about learning something like knockout or angular to help with binding in the future... glad to hear from someone that it can make situations like this easier!

Comment: @aw04 I'll stop spamming your question since I don't have a real answer, But something that comes up to my mind is to give each added row let's say `-1` index and just bind the submit event to e JS function which will make `POST` to your controller with an array of objects (each object is a row) the array index will actually holds the tow position. You just check for existing rows and you won't need the model binder. Just an idea. Good luck

Comment: @Leron No need, I appreciate the ideas! Not a bad one either, I'll have to think about this. Ignoring the model binder all together doesn't seem so bad when it's the only thing holding me back.